# ZF2 autoloading custom controller

Tags: zend-framework2, php-5.3, autoload

I've created a simple application in ZF2. At some point I decided to create a new set of functionalities so I created a new folder this way:

```
module
    Application
        src
            Application
                Controller
                    IndexController.php
            Issue
                Controller
                    FooController.php
```

IndexController has the namespace `Application\Controller` and actions are working fine but when I try to run action from FooController (namespace `Issue\Controller`) it throws `Class 'Issue\Controller\FooController'`. Of course I've set `routes` and `controllers` in configuration (without it it was throwing 404 anyway).

Comment: I think you should make a new module, or a new controller in your old module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that your folder name in `src` should correspond to the folder name of the module. I think this is related to the autoloading namespace magic in ZF2.

So like @Demo suggests you need to do this:

```
module
    Application
        src
            Application
                Controller
                    IndexController.php
    Issue
        src
            Issue
                Controller
                    FooController.php
```

or this:

```
module
    Application
        src
            Application
                Controller
                    IndexController.php
                    FooController.php
```

Read more on the topic [here at this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946234/zf2-application-folder-repetition-in-modules-application-and-modules-applicat)

### EDIT

Read also more on correctly setting up your module, properly autoloading through `autoLoaderConfig` in your `module.php` and `PSR-0` naming conventions [here in the ZF2 user-guid](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.0.5/user-guide/modules.html)

Comment: @jmleroux That depends on your definition of magic. Autoloading using this: `__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/../../src/' . __NAMESPACE__`, looks quite magical to me... Maybe not to you.

Comment: indeed, the use of ```__NAMESPACE__``` can be misunderstood

Comment: So i removed my -1 :)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an autoload problem (but no magic).
You can register your namespace like this (just an quick example) :

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    'Application' => __DIR__ . '/src/Application',
                    'Issue'       => __DIR__ . '/src/Issue',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For PSR-0 compliance, you could put a `Module.php` file in `Application` and `Issue` folders, and the "global" Module.php would look like this :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ .'/src/Application/Module.php';
require_once __DIR__ .'/src/Issue/Module.php';
```

And you could also register your autoloading namespaces in each `Module.php` file.

And again, you should prefer using two modules.

Comment: But maybe you should consider making two modules.

Comment: I am not sure if this is `PSR-0` compliant. I think it is bad practice to register a different namespace in a module like that.

Comment: hence the use of two modules